# Can't get PHP variable in MYSQL query to work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select based on a stored URL, but it won't work:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array('select  * from recs WHERE urlref = ".$URL."');
```

If I hardcode the URL it works. E.g.:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array('select  * from recs WHERE urlref = "http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/"');
```

My $URL variable is fine. If I echo it I get the precise string that is in the database under urlref.

I've tried every possible combination of single- and double-quotes and dots to embed the variable. Any ideas?

Comment: _“Any ideas?”_ – learn some _basics_; go read the manual instead of applying trial-and-error. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thankfully, lots of helpful people totally outnumber you and make you, er, insignificant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '".$URL."'");
```

Always make sure that you put quotes around string values in SQL queries. Otherwise they cannot be interpreted correctly.

Also, please make sure that, when you are using user input, the `$URL` variable is protected against SQL injections. Otherwise I could easily submit a URL like this:

```
' OR '1'='1
```

And it would return all records. Learn more about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I could have sworn I'd tried that, but obviously not. Cheers, mate.

Comment: Ah yeah, I've real_escaped the $URL ok. I'll probably rewrite into PDO as that seems to be the approved way now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping the string literal correctly. You need to escape it using the same quote-mark style you use to delimit it:

```
$data = $db->fetch_all_array('select  * from recs WHERE urlref = \''.$URL.'\'');
```

Alternatively, PHP will automatically parse any variable it finds in a double-quote string, so you could also do:

```
$data = $db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '$URL'");
```

Please be aware though, that it might be better to look into the use of [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) if you're considering using this method for direct user input, or variables whose contents you're not 100% certain to be SQL-escaped.

Comment: Thanks. Outer double-quotes and singles around the variable without dots is neat.

Answer (score 1):

You're using single quotes to encapsulate your string. This means that variables will not expand, and you'll end up with the literal query:

```
select  * from recs WHERE urlref = ".$URL."
```

You either need the following:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array('select  * from recs WHERE urlref = "'.$URL.'"');
//                         ^                                    ^      ^ ^
```

or this:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '".$URL."'");
//                         ^                                    ^      ^ ^
```

or even:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '$URL'");
//                         ^                                         ^
```

**Please make sure that you're `$URL` variable is escaped before pasting it into a database query, or else you're opening your code to SQL injection attacks**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '".$URL."'");
```

you had the dots so if you entered "google.com" it would been ".google.com."

Answer (score 0):

if you use doublequotes (`" "`), the php variable inside them will be parsed like so:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array("select  * from recs WHERE urlref = '{$URL}' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following change in your code:

```
$data=$db->fetch_all_array('select  * from recs WHERE urlref = "'.$URL.'"');
```